# Crear multiples Dataframes de una carpeta con multiples archivos, conservando el nombre del archivo

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

1.- Tengo una direccion que contiene 10 archivos, lo que deseo hacer en la función, es leer cada uno de los 10 archivos de la carpeta y crear un data frame distinto para cada uno de los archivos, pero que conserve el nombre del archivo.

```
def leer_ins(path):
    filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
    return [(pd.read_csv(i)) for i in filenames]

directorio = 'mi ruta'
resultado = leer_ins(directorio)
nombre_archivo0 = resultado[0] #generar os nombres iterativamente
nombre_archivo1 = resultado[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función que necesitas es usar un diccionario, al final te quedaría algo así:

```
def leer_ins(path):
    filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
    dataframes = {}
    for file in filenames:
        dataframes[file.split('/')[-1].replace('.csv', '')] = pd.read_csv(file)
    
    return dataframes
```

### Explicación

- En el diccionario se va guardando el nombre de cada dataframe como clave y el valor es el propio dataframe. Para luego poder consultar cada DataFrame por su nombre de manera sencilla, por ejemplo: `datataframes[df_primero]`. Como se haría con cualquier diccionario
- `dataframes[file.split('/')[-1].replace('.csv', '')] = pd.read_csv(file)`: esta puede ser la parte más compleja del código, aquí cogemos el **string file** y después le  aplicamos el método `split('/')` para separar la ruta por barras y nos qedamos con la última parte usando **slicing** `[-1]` que es el nombre del dataframe. Por último le quitamos el **.csv** con el método `.replace('.csv', '')`
- Por último vamos asignado cada dataframe que leemos a la clave que hemos formado.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Rubiales Alberto, si quisiera añadir el tamaño del archivo, algo cómo "os.stat("file").st_size", sabes cómo podría?, nuevamente muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes crear un diccionario que devuelva una lista, con el tamaño. voy a suponer que sabes sacar el size de cada dataframe, te quedaría así: ```[dataframes[file.split('/')[-1].replace('.csv', '')] = [pd.read_csv(file), size]``` a partir de ahora cuando consultes una clave tendrás una lista con un DataFrame y su peso.